# Which minimal version of Android os is supported for IBM Watson speech to text service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I did download code from https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk#speech-to-text and i did try to build that with android studio. Soon android studio recommended me to download Android SDK Platform 21 (platforms;android-21) with the following error:

```
Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.2
Install Build Tools 21.1.2 and sync project
```

As per my knowledge is it supported since android 5.1. am i right ?
and if yes then according to https://www.statista.com/statistics/271774/share-of-android-platforms-on-mobile-devices-with-android-os/

Still 4.4 has vast amount of users. What should I do to make this sdk to use with it?

Comment: Change the build.gradle file of the demo app to use the target sdk and build tools you normally use.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, whether you want to use the previous SDK or upgrade to the latest. If you are asking about which SDKs IBM supports, a better place to ask that is the IBM support forum, https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html

Comment: well i am asking  which minimum version of android sdk will required for ibm watson-speech-to text api? i go to the link and press ask question button i did get connection refused error so I did post here.

Comment: @brandall okay i did change all build.gradle files with specifying each and every version to 19 and its shows Note: MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
with successful build.